# How to auto capitalize first letter using the kendo Rich Text Editor?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-editor

One of example that cover my requirement is same with MS outlook do.

For example : 
If we type "i am working" then it should be "I am working". It should be automatically when we type this in the first line or in the beginning of sentence (after char ".").  I use the kendo Editor for this.

Can someone help me ? 
I've tried to search in the internet but the solutions are not cover all of my requirements (example MS Outllok). 
Sorry if my question is not clear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(evt){
    var txt = $(this).val();


    // Regex taken from php.js (http://phpjs.org/functions/ucwords:569)
    $(this).val(txt.replace(/^(.)|\s(.)/g, function($1){ return $1.toUpperCase( ); }));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried this but this script convert all the first letter to be capitalized in the every words. What I want is the capitalize in the beginning of sentence only.

Comment: check my second answer

Answer (score 0):

A more object-oriented approach:

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}
```

And then:

```
"hello world".capitalize();  =>  "Hello world"
```

Comment: Hi @snd, I think my requirements are more complex. For example, if we type new sentence then this will be upper case in the first letter automatically after we type space char, or everytime we type a new sentence,  that should be check the "(.) sign" as well. Or in every new line of paragraph ( press enter). 

The other complexity to do this is because The Rich Text contains HTML tags. Therefor I think we need to strip the html tags as well, currently I am still working on it. And the other issue that I've found is to move the caret of cursor position. Thanks